# How to interpret find's info page

Tags: find, info

This is beginning of what I get when I type `info find`

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D DEBUGOPTIONS] [-OLEVEL] [FILE...] [EXPRESSION]

 'find' searches the directory tree rooted at each file name FILE by
```

evaluating the EXPRESSION on each file it finds in the tree.

Is this accurate I assume something inside [] is optional?
Or mandatory?

**Here are some examples of find command:**

```
How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?

find . -name "foo*"
```

How does the following fit here:

```
.
-name
"foo*"
```

Is this info find text that I get outdated by several decades?
Or just incorrect?
Or am I reading it wrong?

EDIT:

After seeing the first answer, I must concure it's not expression. At least judging by man and info page.

```
EXPRESSION
   The part of the command line after the list of starting points is the expression.  This  is  a
   kind  of  query specification describing how we match files and what we do with the files that
   were matched.  An expression is composed of a sequence of things:

   Tests  Tests return a true or false value, usually on the basis of some property of a file  we
          are  considering.   The  -empty  test for example is true only when the current file is
          empty.

   Actions
          Actions have side effects (such as printing  something  on  the  standard  output)  and
          return  either true or false, usually based on whether or not they are successful.  The
          -print action for example prints the name of the current file on the standard output.

   Global options
          Global options affect the operation of tests and actions specified on any part  of  the
          command  line.  Global options always return true.  The -depth option for example makes
          find traverse the file system in a depth-first order.

   Positional options
          Positional optiona affect only tests or actions which follow them.  Positional  options
          always  return  true.   The -regextype option for example is positional, specifying the
          regular expression dialect for regulat expressions occurring later on the command line.

   Operators
          Operators join together the other items within the expression.  They include for  exam‐
          ple  -o  (meaning logical OR) and -a (meaning logical AND).  Where an operator is miss‐
          ing, -a is assumed.

   If the whole expression contains no actions other than -prune or -print, -print  is  performed
   on all files for which the whole expression is true.

   The -delete action also acts like an option (since it implies -depth).
```

It doesn't mention `-name` at all and `-name` doesn't sound like `Test, Action, Global Option, Positional Option or Operator`. And man page doesn't even explain what those things are?

This seems like worst man / info page in history of software documentation.

Comment: `-name` is definitely a `Test`, as described by the documentation. It returns a true or false value based on the file. In your example's case, whether the file's name starts with `foo`.

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not outdated - although the version from the regular manual page (`man find` instead of `info find`) is perhaps easier to understand:

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [expression]
```

In the case of

```
find . -name "foo*"
```

1. `.` is a **path** (referred to as a *FILE* in the info page)
2. `-name "foo*"` is an **expression**

and the other options `[-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel]` are all empty.

Note that GNU find is somewhat unusual in making both `path` and `expression` optional; so the simple command

```
find
```

will find all files (and directories), recursively, starting from the current directory; for portability, you will often see people preferring to specify the current directory explicitly as `.` as in your example.